# Laravel inject SQL Query into Model Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel Controller method with the following code:

```php
$listings = LikedListing::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                ->with('Listing.Photos')
                ->get();
```

This should return a collection of LikedListing records with Photos attached to each likedlisting record.

I have this SQL Query I need to inject into each record as well:

```sql
select u.id, l.address, u.first_name, u.last_name, ll.score
from listings l
         left join liked_listings ll on ll.listing_id = l.id
         left join users u on u.id = ll.user_id
where u.id in (
    select secondary_user
    from user_relationships
    where primary_user = $primaryUser
)
  and ll.listing_id = $listingId
```

Where `$primaryUser = $user->id` And `$listingId` is equal to the `listingid` inside each record in the collection.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Maybe theres a model way of performing this? `UserRelationship` model has a primary_user column, which connects to a $user->id, and there is a secondary_user column, which acts like a follower userid, which is what we need in the final result (a list of all related users per listing)`

**Can someone who has much far superior knowledge with Laravel please assist**

My goal is to have the current collection of listing records with associated photos as well as following users (`secondary_user`) from the `user_relationship` table related to the `primary_user (the logged in user)` who have a record using `user_id` with the `secondary_user value` for that listing in the likedlisting table (obv assoicated with the listing_id). I already provided a raw sql query if thats the only option.

So in simple terms all related users who have liked a listing that the primary user has liked as well should be added to each listing record

Comment: Can you please explain what your primary goal is? Something like "I want to show all Listings, and each one should have its total likes displayed."

Comment: @AkenRoberts added

Comment: I'm assuming you've poured through the [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) documentation already?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane im not going to lie this is a bit confusing to me. can you help?

Comment: Try setting up a really basic example at first. It'll shave off hundreds of lines of your code once you get the hang of it! In particular, the `hasManyThrough` relationship might be of help to you here.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane this is going to take too much time to learn. i was asked to join this project to quickly resolve the prior developers tasks. can i just inject my raw sql query somehow?

Comment: Sure can. Just use [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane can you provide an answer that uses my current code with my raw sql query i need to execute on every record? id really appreciate it. or if you can assist with the model relationships

Comment: @AkenRoberts can you help? im sorry im just lost with this ORM

Comment: Please can you add the code for your `Listing`, `LikedListing` and `User` models